# Angular js detect index when click on a photo from gallery to display a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, bootstrap-modal

My project is a AngularJs, I have a gallery photo, when I click on an image, I have a modal contains all images.

But my problem is: how to detect the index of an image from photo gallery to display the image at the beginning clicker on a modal?

My code:

```
<div class="item_scroll_dek jq-item-sz" ng-repeat="im in sizeImage" ng-class="{active : $last}"
         ng-style="{'background': 'url('+im.image+') no-repeat center transparent', 'background-size': ''+im.x+' '+im.y+''}"
         ng-click="openGallery(userprofile.profile.images)">
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="popupTmplGallery.html">

<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" ng-show="isBusiness" >
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="$index"   ng-repeat="im in userprofile.profile.images track by $index" ng-class="{active : $first}"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner carousel-inner-css">
            <div class="item" ng-repeat="im in galeryProfilBusiness track by $index" ng-class="{active : $first}">
                <img style="width: 100%;" ng-src="{{getImages(im)}}" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control carousel-control-left" href="#Carousel" ng-non-bindable data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control carousel-control-right" href="#Carousel" ng-non-bindable data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
$scope.openGallery = function (images) {

        var modalInstance =  $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'popupTmplGallery.html',
            controller: 'ModaleCtrl',
            scope: $scope ,
            resolve: {
                items: function ()
                {
                    return  images;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (test)
            {
                console.log(test);
            },
            function ()
            {
                console.log('testing');
            });

    };
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `track by $index` on your `ng-repeat`. Then you can pass the index as a parameter on your `ng-click`.

```
<div class="item_scroll_dek jq-item-sz" ng-repeat="im in sizeImage track by $index" ng-class="{active : $last}"
     ng-style="{'background': 'url('+im.image+') no-repeat center transparent', 'background-size': ''+im.x+' '+im.y+''}"
     ng-click="openGallery($index)">
```

---

or you can pass the entire image object like this:

```
<div class="item_scroll_dek jq-item-sz" ng-repeat="im in sizeImage track by $index" ng-class="{active : $last}"
     ng-style="{'background': 'url('+im.image+') no-repeat center transparent', 'background-size': ''+im.x+' '+im.y+''}"
     ng-click="openGallery(im)">
```

In your code behind, you can find the index with [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org).

```js
$scope.openGallery = function(image){ 
  var index = _.indexOf(sizeImage, im);
}
```